# return max value node from a n-nary tree

Tags: c++, tree, max

I am trying to solve the "max value node of a n-nary tree" problem, but I get an exceeded time limit error when the max node is present at the right most place at the lowest level of the tree.

Function for returning tree node pointer:

```
TreeNode<int>* maxDataNode(TreeNode<int>* root) {
    if(root == NULL){
        return root;
    }
    TreeNode<int>* max;
    max = root;

    for(int i =0;i < root->children.size();i++){
        if(maxDataNode(root->children[i])->data > max->data ){
            max=maxDataNode(root->children[i]);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid calling `maxDataNode` twice with the same argument:

```
TreeNode<int>* maxDataNode(TreeNode<int>* root) {
    if(root == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    TreeNode<int>* max;
    max = root;
    for(int i =0;i < root->children.size();i++){
        TreeNode<int> *curr = maxDataNode(root->children[i]);
        if(curr->data > max->data ){
            max=curr;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```